# Integer.toString() vs. Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java

How come the first condition is `false` and the second is `true`?  I was sure they were both true.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(3) == "3");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("3") == 3);
```

Comment: Don't compare reference types like `String` with `==`. `System.out.println(Integer.toString(3).equals("3"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` converts a String to a primitive int and primitives can be compared with `==`. However, `Integer.toString` produces a `String` object and `==` for objects checks that they are the exact same reference; use [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) instead to compare the values of the Strings.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(3).equals("3"));
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("3") == 3);
```

[The above code](https://ideone.com/nsHo0C) outputs:

```
true
true
```

Comment: reference! need to get use to it